# How to show servers dropdown in grafana

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I'm using windows exporter on target server to collect its metricts now i want to show its ip in drop down but what i've found online nothing helped. Can anyone help me show server names mentioned in prometheus.yml file show in the drop down

[image]

[image]

Comment: can check if the same query gives you the output in prometheus-node:9090. If instance is a variable then you need to add "$" before it

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible if you have multiple jobs running. for example you are checking host resources as Job1 and some application resources Job2. Then to fetch instance related to any job you need to specify jobname along with the metric. So here you should add `label_values(windows_system_system_uptime{job=$that_job_name},instance)`

Comment: can you add the screenshot of prometheus screen i.e. IP:9090 and with query windows_system_system_uptime. And then also go to status->targets->windows exporter-> click on that link --> search the metrics and see if you get this system uptime metrics. Attach here.